# Unlocking Battleframes

Tags: firefall

In Firefall you can unlock Battle suits with Red Bean Tokens but I recently discovered on a forum that there is an alternative method. What is this alternative method? The forum asks the same question.

Comment: This actually isn't a duplicate because they've hidden where you have to spend those 10 pilot tokens ... it's in the Battleframe Garage.  You'll see a button on the right side that says 'Battleframes', and that will let you spend your pilot tokens.  If you go to a Battleframe Station, it will cost you red beans.

Comment: @Joe post this as an answer you deserve the rep.

Comment: I can't, once it's marked as a duplicate, it's considered closed and you're not allowed to add new answers.  (although you're still allowed to up-vote existing answers)  And the answer doesn't really fit the other question.  Oh, I should also mention that I found this once, then spent weeks trying to re-find it.  Even asked on zone chat, as I knew it existed, and I only got one response (which was wrong ... told me to go to Devil's Tusk and use the crafting station).